# Particle moving under force $F=-cx^3$

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, energy

A particle with mass $m$ moves under influence of a force  $F=-cx^3$, with $c$ a constant. What is the potential energy function $V(x)$?

And if it starts to move from rest from position $x=-a$, what is the velocity at $x=0$?

Comment: I think if the potential is only a function of position, then you can say that **F** = -$\nabla V(x)$.  So if you integrate F with respect to x, I think you should be able to find V(x).

Comment: so $V(x)=-\frac{c}{4}x^4$? but what is then the velocity at $x=0$?

Comment: I think you have a sign error, but once you have potential, you can just conserve energy to get the answer for which you are looking.

Comment: you can use conservation of energy; at the start is it at rest but has potential energy $V(-a)$. At the end it has converted some (or all, depending on your integration constant) of this to kinetic energy, from which you can find the velocity

Comment: alternatively you can use Newton's second law and do some integration...

Comment: See this [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15620/392) for how to handle non uniform acceleration cases.