# Finding the distance travelled during change in velocity from $v_i$ to $v_f$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, power

A constant power is applied to a particle of mass m. The velocity of the particle increases from $v_i$ to $v_f$. We have to find the distance travelled by the particle during this interval.(neglect friction)

$$P=Fv_f$$
$$P=mav_f$$
$$P=\frac{mv_f(v_f^2-v_i^2)}{2S}$$
$$S=\frac{mv_f(v_f^2-v_i^2)}{2P}$$

where

P=>Power

F=>Force

m=>Mass

S=>Distance

However the correct answer is supposed to be $\frac{m(v_f^3-v_i^3)}{3P}$. Can anyone explain  this.

Comment: Very related to this SE question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211078/terminal-velocity-and-distance-traveled-with-constant-but-limited-power/211109#211109

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**
 Using Chain rule, We get $a= \frac{vdv}{dx}$,

$$
P=constant\\
P=F.v\\
P=(ma).v\\
\\
P=\left(m\frac{v\space dv}{dx}\right).v
$$
Now Integrate,