# Kinematics and varying accleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

If accleration varies inversely with square of displacement then how can we find the time it takes to cover distance **S??**
**My attempt**
I tried to use calculus  but didn't, work at all please help.

Comment: See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15620/392) to a similar enough question. And please show your attempt when posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't entirely answer the question, but it might help.

As you know, one way of finding the time  $t$ is by finding an equation that relates $t$ to any of $a$, $v$ or the displacement $x.$ 
$ $ $ $ AFAIK, it doesn't seem obvious to find $t$ without such an equation.

(As you know, since $a$ is not constant, the formulae of UAM won’t work here, even if you know $a$, $v$ and $x$)

Also, to find $v$, you can proceed as follows.

We know

$$a=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Then from the relationship
$$a=v\frac{dv}{dx},$$
We have 
$$v\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$
You can now find $v$ as a function of $x$ by integrating with respect to $x$.