# How can I find $v(t)$ if I'm given $x(v)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

The given is the distance but the variable is the velocity $x(v)=k \,v^2$. I want to find the velocity $v(t)$.

Comment: Relevant post FYI - https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15620/392

Answer (score 3):

The given relation implies that at all times $t$, the function $x(t)$ obeys
$$
x(t) = k \left( \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \right)^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{x(t)}{k}}
$$
This is just a differential equation for $x(t)$ and so can be solved for $x(t)$ using standard ODE techniques.  (Note, in particular, that it is a separable equation.)  Once this is done, the result can be differentiated to find $v(t)$.

Comment: This is only true if the LHS is meant to mean $x(v):=x(v(t)):=x(t)$, no?!

Comment: @JasonFunderberker:  I'm not quite sure what you mean there, but I've tried to clarify what I mean in the first sentence.  If it doesn't address your concerns, please follow up.

Answer (score 0):

$x = kv^2
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow v = \frac {dx}{dt} = 2kv \frac {dv}{dt}$

One trivial solution is that $x=v=0$ for all $t$. However, if $v \ne 0$ then we have

$\displaystyle 2k \frac {dv}{dt} = 1
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {dv}{dt} = \frac 1 {2k}$

You can integrate this to find $v$ as a function of $t$. Integrating introduces a constant of integration, which you can set equal to the initial velocity $v|_{t=0}$.